# Choosing which parameter to use

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report that is populated by a View.  I have 4 parameters.  I want to be able to filter by one parameter at a a time.

Parameters are Studio, Division, Supervisor, Date.  I need to be able to filter by any parameter alone.  So, if I filter by Studio I need all data for that studio no matter what the division, supervisor or date are.  I need to be able to do that with all 4 parameters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Using version 14.1.6.1702

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out.  4 parameters pop up at the same time when the report is opened.  The user just has to choose which one he wants to filter by and the other 3 parameters the user adds all values.  This accomplishes what I needed.

```
To filter by a single division:
area - choose all values
studio - choose all values
division - choose only 'east' division
date - choose all values
```

This will result in all areas, studios, and dates that correspond to the east division.